# what prediction maximize absolute cube loss?

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, machine-learning

As   1) mode maximize L0 loss, 
     2) median maximize L1 loss, 
     3) mean maximize L2 Loss.

I'm wondering what about L3 loss?

Comment: In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: I mean you could ask the same question about the $L^4$ loss, the $L^5$ loss, and so on. There can't be different names for all the possible statistics, they are just various examples of [M-estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator). By the way, the $L^\infty$ loss is minimized by the [midrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-range).

Comment: I'm more interested in whether there are any explicit general functions that exist except minimizing a polynomial function.